# How can I build an RPM for an earlier version of python?

Tags: python, rpm

How can I build a python distribution RPM that is only dependent on an *earlier* version of python?

**Why?**  I'm trying to build a distribution RPMs for RHEL6/CentOS 6, which only includes Python 2.6, but I am building usually on machines with Python 2.7.

This is an open source project, and I have already ensured that it shouldn't be including any libraries/APIs that are not in 2.6.

I am building the RPMs with:

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm
```

---

**setup.py file:**

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='pyresttest',
    version='0.1',
    description=Text',
    maintainer='Not listing here',
    maintainer_email='no,just no',
    url='project url here',
    keywords='rest web http testing',
    packages=['pyresttest'],
    license='Apache License, Version 2.0',
    requires=['yaml','pycurl']
)
```

(Specifics removed for the url, maintainer, email and description).

The RPM appears to be valid, but when I try to install on RHEL6, I get this error:
python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by pyresttest-0.1-1.noarch

There should be some way to get it to override the default python version to require, or supply a custom SPEC file, but after several hours of fiddling with it, I'm stuck. Ideas?

---

EDIT: I suppose I should clarify why I'm doing a RPM for python code, instead of just using setuptools or pip: this will hopefully go to production at work, where all deployments are RPM-based and most VMs are still RHEL6.  Asking them to adopt another packaging tool is likely to be a non-starter, since our company is closely tied to the RPM format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-organized the answer.

Actually, there's no "rpm-package". There're rpm-packages for RHEL6, rpm-packages for FedoraNN, rpm-packagse for OpenSUSE-X.Y and so on. And besides there're Debian, Ubuntu, Arch and Gentoo :)

You have the following possibilities with your Python package:

1. You may completely avoid rpm-, deb- and other "native linux packaging systems",  and may opt to use a "python-native" packaging system like [PIP](https://pip.pypa.io/en/1.5.X/index.html). Thus you completely avoid the complexity and lack of compatibility between packaging systems in various versions and various flavours of Linux. And for a package which doesn't "infiltrate" deeply into "core system", this could be the best solution.
2. You may continue to use RPM as an archive format for your package but completely turn off automatic dependency calculations. This can be done with `AutoReqProv: no` directive in the spec. To be able to work with a customized spec one may use `--spec-only` and `--spec-file` [distutils options](https://docs.python.org/2.0/dist/creating-rpms.html). But remember that a package built this way is even worse than a zip from p.1: without proper dependencies it contains less necessary metainformation and thus "defames" the whole idea behind Linux packaging systems which were invented to built consistent systems, to avoid problems like "DLL hell" and to be suitable for automatic maintainance and updates. Actually you may add dependency information manually, via `Requires: <something>` tag but this may become even more hard and bporing if you target several Linux platforms at once.
3. In order to take into account all those complex and boring details and nuances of a particular package system you may create "build sandboxes" with appropriate versions of necessary Linux flavours. My preferred way to create such sandboxes is to use pre-created ["OpenVZ templates"](http://wiki.openvz.org/Download/template/precreated), but without OpenVZ per se: simply unpack a given archive into a subdirectory (being `root` to preserve permissions), then `chroot` into the subdirectory, and voila! you've got Debian, RHEL etc... Fedora people have created [Mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock) for the same purposes and likely `Mock` would be a more elaborated solution. As @BobMcGee suggests in the comment one also may consider [Jenkins Docker plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin)

Once you have a build sandbox with python distribution specific to that system, distutils etc you may automate the build process using simple scripting, bash or python.

That's it.

Comment: So, 2 questions about this answer: 1) if it's intrinsic to automatic dependency calculations, would building on a Python 2.6 system solve this?  2) Is there a way to supply a custom .SPEC file for the python build to use (something I'm accustomed to doing with Maven)?  (I'm pretty comfortable with writing RPM .spec files, but would like to avoid doing completely manual rpm-build if possible).

Comment: 1. Well, not completely. Dependency calculation machinery is slightly changed from time to time and especially from one major release to another. For most python packages such changes are not that important because these packages are neither intended for "core system" nor rely on it, but sometimes it matters. So installing python2.6 may help for your particular case but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Docker + Jenkins + Jenkins Docker-Workflow plugin is probably the best way to accomplish this now.   You would define docker environments for your core distributions, build RPMs in each (with slightly different specfiles if needed), and go from there.

Comment: I only know because.... now I have the capability to do it.  And I'm managing a multi-environment build pipeline for a product. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not do very much python work but have done some RPM packaging.  You probably need to somehow do what one would normally do in the RPM's spec file and specify and require a particular release of your python package like so ...

```
# this would be in your spec file
requires: python <= 2.6
```

Take a look here for more info:

http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-manual-dependencies.html